# salty-/cypress-testrail-reporter not posting results to TR

Tags: cypress, reporters, testrail

I have my tests written on Cypress. And now need to report results to TestRail.
Cypress.json has correct config specified and I see that reporter create new Run in TR correctly, but after test completion results are not posted.

Do I need to specify some versions, or what might be failing?

Issue is in testrail.js:

````
...
 axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: this.base + "/get_runs/" + this.projectId,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            auth: {
                username: this.options.username,
                password: this.options.password,
            }// no request maid

        }).then(function (response) {
            _this.runId = response.data[0].id;
            responce = response.data[0].id;
            publishToAPI(); // no request maid
        });

...```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved myself. 
Issue was that reporter not post results in 'headed mode.'